# React Native app builds multiple times rapidly then fails when in production mode in Expo

Tags: react-native, expo

Despite the app running perfectly in test builds, when I publish the app or put in in production mode the app builds once that takes a while, then several times within short succession as seen below:

[image]

[image]

After it stops I then receive the errors:

> "Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling
>   runApplication)"

and

> "undefined is not a function (evaluating
>   'babelHelpers.objectDestructuringEmpty(d.actions)')"

I have looked up this issue and found that those 2 error messages tend to be vague "catch-all" errors, however none of the posts I found had the rapid build issue I have, so that may a key part to solving this. I have tried restarting the app several times, npm install-ing, updating react and expo to their latest versions, and other small non-code related fixes however none have worked.

Here is a link to my repo: https://github.com/tc1240/AT-Assist. If anyone has had this or can take a look at my code any help is appreciated. Thank you,

Also this is my first question asked on stack so I apologize in advance if my question does not follow some of the guidelines.

Answer (score 0):

I've been experiencing this lately, since I tried publishing for Android and iOS.

I'm currently unable to build additional projects in Expo other than the one I'm working on, so I can't test your project, but:

Can you add the `android.package` key in your `app.json` file and try running again? Restoring this back into my project seemed to fix the issue for me.